Number of Islands, C++17, Visual Studio
I have written a program in C++ to answer the problem of the number of islands. I receive (a path to) a text file that consists of an array where . is water, and the rest island.
I need to find the number of islands represented by the 2d array.
As an example:
+++..............
+++......++++....
++.......^^@+.+..
*......+++**+++^+

Here you would have 2 islands.
I receive the file path as an argument and I used a DFS approach to solve this algorithm. I want to make sure that my code is clean, so I'm happy to receive any feedback you guys might have!
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <stack>
#include <filesystem>

#define MAP_HEIGHT 50
#define MAP_WIDTH 80

bool IsValidIndex(const int pos_row, const int pos_col, const int mapHeight, const int mapWidth) {
    return (pos_row > 0) && (pos_row < mapHeight) && (pos_col > 0) && (pos_col < mapWidth);
}

bool IsTerrain(const char c) {
    return !(c == '.');
}

void DfsLand(std::array<std::array<char, MAP_WIDTH>, MAP_HEIGHT>& map, const int start_i, const int start_j, const int mapHeight, const int mapWidth) {
    std::stack<std::pair<int, int>> toVisit;
    toVisit.push({ start_i, start_j });
    while (!toVisit.empty()) {
        int row = toVisit.top().first;
        int col = toVisit.top().second;
        toVisit.pop();

        map[row][col] = '.';

        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                if (IsValidIndex(row + i, col + j, mapHeight, mapWidth) && IsTerrain(map[row+i][col+j])) {
                    toVisit.push({ row + i, col + j });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(const int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "In order to use the program, please provide the name of a map file";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::filesystem::path filePath(argv[1]);
    std::filesystem::path filePath("map1_6islands.txt");

    if (filePath.extension() != ".txt" && filePath.extension() != ".text") {
        std::cout << "Please provide a .txt file for this program to work correctly" << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

   
    std::ifstream landscapeFile(filePath);

    const unsigned int mapHeight = MAP_HEIGHT;
    const unsigned int mapWidth = MAP_WIDTH;

    std::array<std::array<char, mapWidth>, mapHeight> map;

    if (landscapeFile.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        int i = 0;
        while (std::getline(landscapeFile, line)) {
            std::move(line.begin(), line.end(), map[i].begin());
            i++;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file " << filePath.filename() << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int nbIslands = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mapHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapWidth; j++) {
            if (IsValidIndex(i, j, mapHeight, mapWidth) && IsTerrain(map[i][j])) {
                DfsLand(map, i, j, mapHeight, mapWidth);
                nbIslands++;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "number of islands " << nbIslands << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


I don’t do reviews involving Visual Studio because I’ve never used it, but I don’t see what Visual Studio has to do with any of this.

Make sure the complexity is linear. DFS to find connected components is linear time.

@MazHoot, Curious why !(c == '.') instead of c != '.'?

I'm not quite sure whether an input of "a.\n.b" should be considered as representing two islands or just one.

I’m voting to close this question because the code fails to compile. There is a redeclaration error. Given the amount of work being done in main(...) and the question involving reading from a file, the broken code is relevant to the actual review. This post should have been flagged to fix the issue, but an answer was given which prevents the poster from updating the code. If the poster decides to repost this problem with the error fixed, I'd be happy to leave a review.

As the double declaration of path filePath has not been mentioned in the first review, I'd be contented if you fix this in the code you present for review.

Here are some suggestions:

We can use std::vector instead of std::array. This allows map dimensions to be determined at runtime. Note that std::vector can also be used like std::stack.
We don't need std::move if we treat a string like a vector<char>.
We can handle a jagged map by padding with water entries.
We can reduce the number of index checks by handling each direction (up, down, left, right) separately. Since each island is first detected on its top row, we only need to check upwards when start_i < row. The original code allows land tiles to connect diagonally, which I am not sure is intended (consider a checkerboard pattern).
Since each character is either land or not land (water), we can use a vector<vector<bool>> is_land for the DFS runs. This reduces the auxillary storage required.

Below is an implementation with the suggestions:
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;

int count_islands(const vector<std::string> &map) {
    // compute dimensions (m rows, n cols)
    int m = map.size();
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        n = std::max(n, (int) map[i].size());

    // is_land[i][j]: whether map[i][j] is land
    // note: default bool is false (pad jagged maps)
    vector<vector<bool>> is_land(m, vector<bool>(n));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].size(); ++j)
            if (map[i][j] != '.')
                is_land[i][j] = true;

    // check for land tiles
    int count = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < m; ++a) {
        for (int b = 0; b < n; ++b) {
            // if you find land, count it
            // and sink the island it belongs to
            if (is_land[a][b]) {
                ++count;

                vector<std::pair<int, int>> to_sink{{a, b}};
                while (!to_sink.empty()) {
                    int row = to_sink.back().first;
                    int col = to_sink.back().second;
                    to_sink.pop_back();

                    is_land[row][col] = false;

                    // right
                    int c_R = col + 1;
                    if (c_R < n && is_land[row][c_R])
                        to_sink.push_back({ row, c_R });

                    // down
                    int r_D = row + 1;
                    if (r_D < m && is_land[r_D][col])
                        to_sink.push_back({ r_D, col });

                    // left
                    int c_L = col - 1;
                    if (col > 0 && is_land[row][c_L])
                        to_sink.push_back({ row, c_L });

                    // up
                    int r_U = row - 1;
                    if (row > a && is_land[r_U][col])
                        to_sink.push_back({ r_U, col });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

Here are some test cases:
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test 1: Islands = " << count_islands({
        }) << "\n";

    std::cout << "Test 2: Islands = " << count_islands({
        "+++..............",
        "+++......++++....",
        "++.......^^@+.+..",
        "*......+++**+++^+"
    }) << "\n";

    std::cout << "Test 3: Islands = " << count_islands({
        "o",
        ".o",
        "o.o",
        ".o.o"
    }) << "\n";

    std::cout << "Test 4: Islands = " << count_islands({
        "ooooooo",
        "......o",
        "ooooo.o",
        "o...o.o",
        "o.o.o.o",
        "o.ooo.o",
        "o.....o",
        "ooooooo",
    }) << "\n";

    return 0;
}

Great job on making a reproducible example!

Text "Test N Islands" at first sounds like the expected island result count and not the sequence number.  Suggest also posting the expected island count.
